# How to print unique values from each for loop?

Tags: python

Disclaimer; I have only picked up Python a week ago or so, so excuse me for any bad syntax and stuff like that.

I have attemped a little program in Python which roll 6 dices and keeps going until it gets 6 sixes. It then counts the number of rolls needed. This went well, however, i've decided to let the user decide how many times this process is repeated, and add each number of rolls needed to a list.

My problem is that if i for an example let the program run 3 times, the list in the end contain the LAST number of rolls needed 3 times, instead of 3 unique values.

```
import random as rd

rollsum = 0
rollno = 0
n=int(input("How many times do you want to roll 6 sixes?"))
g=[]

for _ in range(n):
    while rollsum != 36:
        a, b, c, d, e, f = (rd.randint(1, 6) for k in range(6))  # The die get assigned a random value between 1 and 6
        rollsum = a + b + c + d + e + f  # The sum of the die is calculated
        rollno += 1  # The number of rolls is increased by 1
        print()
        print("Roll:", a, b, c, d, e)  # Prints the value of each of the 6 die
        print("Sum:", rollsum)  # Prints the sum of the 6 sie
        print("Roll number:", rollno)  # Prints the number of rolls
    g.append(rollno)

print(g)
```

Comment: jfye: `dices = random.choices(range(1,7),6)` and `rollsum = sum(dices)` and `print("Roll:",*dices)`  ( you never print dice `f` btw) AND you append the rollno - not the sum of your dices  to `g`

Comment: You need to reset the number of rolls for each "pick", so `rollno = 0` should move just above the `while`. And so should `rollsum = 0` as you also want to reset the "matched target". Alternatively you could use `while True` and `if rollsum == 36: break` (essentially a do...while loop).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import random as rd

n=int(input("How many times do you want to roll 6 sixes?"))
g=[]

for i in range(n):
    rollno = 0
    rollsum = 0
    while rollsum != 36:
        a, b, c, d, e, f = (rd.randint(1, 6) for k in range(6))  # The die get assigned a random value between 1 and 6
        rollsum = a + b + c + d + e + f  # The sum of the die is calculated
        rollno += 1  # The number of rolls is increased by 1
        print()
        print("Roll:", a, b, c, d, e)  # Prints the value of each of the 6 die
        print("Sum:", rollsum)  # Prints the sum of the 6 sie
        print("Roll number:", rollno)  # Prints the number of rolls
    g.append(rollno)

print(g)
```

The reason your code failed ealier is that after the first time, `rollsum` was 36 and therefore it didn't enter the inner loop. The second thing was that `rollno` kept the previous count. So my change was to initialize both in the outer loop and not outside.

Comment: Everyone was  newbie once :)